# DataContext.Executequery login failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, iis, linq-to-sql

I use Linq to sql and have the following statement:

```
 myDataContext ctx = new myDataContext();
  string query = "select * from myTable";
  var mycollection = ctx.ExecuteQuery<t_entity>(query).ToList();
```

This code works well with my domain user but not with the user running the IIS application pool which has lower privileges. It is important to note that this is a massive system with thousands of calls to the database and no similar issue have ever been observed.

Any comment will be highly appreciated.

All the best
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your connection string? I suppose it uses `Integrated Security`, so it tries to use your current windows account for DB connection. But in case of IIS - it will use different user - IIS application pool user. There are three typical ways to resolve this:

1. Create specific SQL user with password, and then specify it in the connection string. So it will use plain SQL credentials and not Windows account
2. Allow IIS application pool (IIS APPPOOL\YourAppPoolName) to access SQL server by adding it to Logins list in SQL server and allow access to specific DB. But in that case both SQL server and Web Server with IIS should be under the same Active Directory domain, as SQL server should know about local application pool user from WebServer.
3. Create a new windows user and configure IIS to use this windows user to execute application pool on behalf of that user. And then allow this user to access to SQL server. But this user should have minimal rights, as it's not soo secure, as your web app will have permissions of that user and it might be a security whole

Comment: The user running the app pool is already a domain user. It just has minimum privieliege following sql server best practices.

Comment: Can you post your connection string then? Without specific password. Because if apppool is running under domain user, and ConnectionString is using Trusted Identity, then it should work fine

Comment: Data Source=db_server_name;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=NameofMyDatabase

Comment: hm, it looks fine. Does this domain user exists in the SQL server logins list and has access to your DB? Does this user is used in other web apps that is working fine?

Comment: Yes, and it has db_datareader, db_datawriter,db_executor and public database role on the require databases

Comment: This user is only used on this application. This web app has more than 150 000 lines of code and all working fine under this user. Most of the existing code uses stored procedure and dynamic sql.  This newer code introduced uses some of the features in linq

Comment: hm, does linq uses the same connection string? By default when we create a new linq context, it uses own that was used during context creation, so it will be separated connection string. You can check it in web.config and also in `myDataContext` constructor

Comment: This sounds more like it. I will check and get back

Comment: Connection string was the problem